# Entity Framework Relationship binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to make a shopping cart, but I'm stack from accessing the Product Name from `Cart`.

Here is the model for `Product`

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the model for `Cart`

```
public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string CartID { get; set; }
    public int Quanity { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the temporary `IActionResult` to view the cart

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var cartItem = _context.CartItems.Where(a => a.CartID == "abcd").ToList();

        return View(cartItem);
    }
```

and this is the view for `IActionResult`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @item.Product.Name <br />
}
```

and this is `RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

it was working when i only use `@item.ItemID`, `@item.CartID`, `@item.Quantity`, `@item.ProductID`. How can I get the name of the product from cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the related entity (`Product`) as part of your query using [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method:

```
var cartItem = _context.CartItems.Include(ci=>ci.Products)
                                 .Where(a => a.CartID == "abcd")
                                 .ToList();
```